# MvvmCross IoC and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, mvvmcross

I have created and app where I need to access the data via a WCF data service on the web.  I have set up my Core, Droid and iOS projects.  I use svcutil to generate the classes and such to access the WCF Service.  This will only work in the Droid app due to libraries missing in the Portable project.  My ViewModel is as follows

```
public class MapViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    IMyAppService MyAppService;

    CompositeType data;

    public MapViewModel(IMyAppService MyAppService)
    {
        this.MyAppService = MyAppService;
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        //TODO: Add starting logic here

        data = await MyAppService.SayHello("Jim");

        //return base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

In my core project, I also describe the interface:

```
public interface IMyAppService
{
    Task<CompositeType> SayHello(string Name);
}
```

All good so far.  I implement the interface in my Droid project:

```
public sealed class WhatNowService : IWhatNowService
{

    private static string ServiceUri = "WhatNow.svc";

    public WhatNowClient NewClient()
    {
        BasicHttpsBinding binding = DataModel.CreateBasicHttp();

        WhatNowClient client = new WhatNowClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(ServiceUri));
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Settings.Domain + "\\" + Settings.UserName;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Settings.Password;

        return client;
    }


    public async Task<CompositeType> SayHello(string Name)
    {
        CompositeType ret = new CompositeType();
        ret.BoolValue = true;
        ret.StringValue = Name;

        try
        {
            WhatNowClient client = NewClient();
            ret = await Task<CompositeType>.Factory.FromAsync((asyncCallback, asyncState) => client.BeginGetDataUsingDataContract(ret, asyncCallback, asyncState),
               (asyncResult) => client.EndGetDataUsingDataContract(asyncResult), null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Since it ends with "Service", it should get registered as a lazy singleton.  So this brings us to the output from svcutil.  Here is a snippet:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System;


[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CompositeType", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.WCF")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class CompositeType : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private bool BoolValueField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string StringValueField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BoolValueField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.BoolValueField.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                this.BoolValueField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("BoolValue");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.StringValueField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.StringValueField, value) != true))
            {
                this.StringValueField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("StringValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The point is that it contains the definition for "CompositeType".  If I put this code in the Core project, all the types are available to all projects, but it won't compile because a Portable project doesn't have System.Runtime.Serialization among other things.  If I put it in the Droid project, then the Core project doesn't know what a CompositeType is.  Ultimately, I think the svcutil output needs to be in the Droid project.  Is there a way for the Core project to be able to see the CompositeType type?  Is there a better way that I could do this?  It seems like a .Net Core Library might be better going forward than a Portable Library for being able to use WCF.  Is this a consideration for future MvvmCross versions?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) library.

.NET Standard is the replacement for portable libraries on the .NET platform, and nearly all of the .NET Framework APIs have cross-platform support (some BCL libraries that are not available out-of-the-box are available on NuGet).

Comment: The problem is that MvvmCross won't load into a .Net Standard project at this time.  Unless something has changed recently.

Comment: I just tried and MvvmCross did load, but it is worse than the portable library when it comes to compiling the svcutil classes.  It seems that .Net Standard leaves out System.ServiceModel.  Do you know of a way around that?

Comment: I loaded a package called System.ServiceModel.Primitives and it compiles now.  The only warnings I get are that the MvvmCross packages may not be compatible because they target .Net 4.6.1.

Comment: You might want to contact the MvvmCross team about that. They are [targeting *both* `netstandard2.0` and `net461`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/MvvmCross.csproj), but they don't need `net461` if they target `netstandard2.0`.

Comment: They are tagged here so maybe they will see it.  In any case, switching to a .Net Standard 2.0 Core fixed the problem I asked about so I will mark your answer as the Answer.